# How to insert records into table with records from a table function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a setup as mentioned below

```
> create table earnings(earning_id number,
>                      col1 number,
>                      col2 number);
>
>create table trans(trans_id number,
>                   trans_attr1 number,
>                   trans_attr2 number);
>
>create or replace type trans_obj as object
>                   (trans_id number,
>                    trans_attr1 number,
>                    trans_attr2 number);
>
>create or replace type trans_coll as table of trans_obj;
>
>create or replace type earning_obj as object 
> (
>  earning_id number,
>  col1 number,
>  col2 number
>  );
>
>create or replace type earnings_coll as table of earnings_obj;
>
>/
```

I have a table function as below

> > function calculate(trans_t trans_coll)
> >       return earnings_coll pipelined;

I would like to do something like below

```
>>  function get_results(trans_t trans_coll)
>>  return earnings_coll pipelined 
>>   as
>>      l_earning_rec earnings_obj;
>>    
>>   begin
>>     
>>     for earning in (select * from table(calculate(trans_t)))
>>      loop
>>         l_earning_rec.extend();
>>         // copy value from earning to l_earning_rec without having to copy each
>>         // attribute individually
>>         
>>         pipe row(l_earning_rec);
>>      end loop;
>>    
>>    return;
>>   end get_results;
```

Please let me know if there is a way to do this.

Also if get_results was a procedure which would just insert records to earnings table,how can I do something like

```
insert into earnings 
   values (select * from table(calculate(trans_t)))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change the function to this if it helps:

```
for earning in (select earnings_obj(earning_id, col1, col2) a
                 from table(calculate(trans_t)))
loop
   pipe row(earning.a);
end loop;
```

as for your insert you would just write it as:

```
insert into earnings 
select * from table(calculate(trans_t));
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been studying PL/SQL using the "10g PL/SQL programming guide" and i dont think there is such thing like this.

Comment: Thanks Jeyvison, Which part exactly are you saying cannot be done?

Comment: Sorry ^^. You cant copy a row. You have to copy all the attributes or use a SELECT Statement if it helps..